# Wronskian for non-homogeneous second order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Q. Consider the ODE: $u''(t)+P(t)u'(t)+Q(t)u(t)=R(t),\ t\in[0,\ 1]$. There exists continuous functions $P,Q$ and $R$ defined on $[0,\ 1]$ and two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ of this ODE such that

1. $W(t)=2t-1 \ \  \forall t\in[0,\ 1]$
2. $W(t)=\sin 2\pi t \ \  \forall t\in[0, \ 1]$
3. $W(t)=\cos 2\pi t\ \ \forall t\in[0,\ 1]$
4. $W(t)=1 \ \ \forall t\in[0,\ 1]$

I observe that for some non-homogeneous problems like $$y''-3y'+2y=2,$$the wronskian $W(t)=W(y_1(t),y
_2(t))$ for the linearly independent solutions $y_1(t)=e^t+1$ and $y_2(t)=e^{2t}+1$ do have an isolated zero on $\mathbb R$. How can we find $P,Q$ and $R$ satisfying $W(t)=2t-1$ for some solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ or how to reject the possibility?

Comment: For $P(x)$ you can use Abel's identity.. Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity

Comment: @user577215664 That identity is suitable only for homogeneous case ($R(t)=0)$, right?

Comment: Yes it's for homogeneous case.